# Quarkus - Modular Rest Endpoints in Gradle Multi-Project Build

Tags: gradle, quarkus, gradle-multi-project-build

Is it possible to create a gradle multi-project build with following gradle-projects that depend on each other and contain Quarkus REST-Endpoints, that are then available in the started server?

- core
- module1 (contains quarkus rest-endpoints and depends on core)
- module2 (contains quarkus rest-endpoints and depends on core)
- server1 (includes module1 and module2 and depends on core)

The server1 project should be the typical quarkus-application that contains its `application.conf` and can be startable and has a Hello-World Rest-Endpoint.

The module1 defines some quarkus rest-endpoints

When server1 is started all! rest-endpoints (including those of module1 and module2) must be available.

Can someone give me an example how to achieve this, as i can not seem to get it to work, that a REST-Endpoint that is outside of "server1" is ever published/available to the web, when i start server1.

When i talk of REST-Endpoints i mean:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive

When i talk of Gradle Multi-Project i mean:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html

Im using:

- Quarkus 3.8.2

For my example-project where i can not get it to work, see:

- https://github.com/funkrusher/fk-framework-quarkus-jooq/tree/experiment-multi-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution how to do this now, after some research.

The @Path Annotations of the REST-Endpoints are considered as "Beans".

When reading the gradle-tooling section of the quarkus-documentation carefully, we can see in the chapter "Working with multi-module projects", that we need to do something to make quarkus discover the beans in other modules

- see: https://quarkus.io/guides/gradle-tooling

because by default, quarkus does not discover beans in other projects of the multi-module project.

So the solution can be to defined the "jandex" plugin in the `gradle.build` file of the "module1" and "module2" projects. Then the "server1" project will load all beans (including @Path annotated) at startup.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.kordamp.gradle.jandex'
}

// needed, so jandex does not throw an error for enums. See: https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/issues/7659
jandex {
    version = '3.1.5'
}
```

Alternatively (and more recommended) it is also possible to create a folder `src/main/resources/META-INF` in the `module1` and `module2` project, and put a file `beans.xml` into this folder. That way quarkus will also recognize those projects as relevant for bean-discovery.